# Hide "disk password" login option at EFI (Filevault) login screen

Tags: filevault, login, efi

I encrypted my volume before installation and have added my user as FileVault user afterwards.

Now I can login with either the disk password or my user login password at the EFI (Filevault) login screen. (The former option sends me to the regular OS X login screen where I can again login as my user.)

How do I hide the disk password login option at the EFI login screen without enabling the input menu (com.apple.loginwindow showInputMenu -bool TRUE)?

In other words: How do I go from disk password-based encryption to login password-based encryption, at least cosmetically?

Is there maybe some option for com.apple.loginwindow that one can use?
Can *.efires files be edited?
Can Core Storage metadata for the volume somehow be edited?

Comment: I can't think of any way to do what you want other than to turn off FileVault and then re-enable it again. After it's finished, you should only have a user login prompt that comes before the Apple symbol.

Comment: I did the same thing, ran into the same problem, and ended up decrypting and reencrypting to make it go away.  At least the process is pretty simple, although it requires two reboots and a few hours to complete.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem when booting from an external drive, but not my internal drive!

When I boot normally, I only see a one FileVault option: me. However, when booting from my USB drive, I see two: me, and "Disk Password".

Investigating with fdesetep (`sudo fdesetup list —extended`) shows that the internal drive has:

```
ESCROW  UUID                                                                     TYPE USER
        BCF2ABC6-40F8-4F31-A508-7284BC85E65A                   Personal Recovery User
        2EE7445C-13C0-497D-AD54-DA1B8D22A0F7                                  OS User ben
```

However, the external drive has:

```
ESCROW  UUID                                                                     TYPE USER
        EB313C9F-E27C-41D5-9EE3-192490C792BE                     Disk Passphrase User
        92ACE5CE-7187-44DB-92CE-56344C18568D                                  OS User ben
```

Note that the external drive doesn't have a recovery key set (confirmed with `fdesetup haspersonalrecoverykey` returning `false`).

It looks like it should be possible to remove the Disk Passphrase using fdesetup, by doing `fdesetup remove --uuid <the UUID of Disk Passphrase>`. I would strongly recommend adding a recovery key, if you do this.

Comment: This did the trick for me. Once I removed the user with 'Disk Passphrase User' with fdesetup it disappeared from the EFI Login Window.

Answer (score 0):

I **think** the answer to your question may be within the realm of the `fdesetup` command. (I am not absolutely certain only because I have not run into your exact situation myself.)

You will want to read over the man page carefully, as it is probably fairly easy using such an enterprise-type command to yank on some digital short hairs in a distracting and painful manner.

Also, take a look at [Rich Trouton’s blog](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/) for his postings regarding FileVault and `fdesetup` which may be better to start with than reading the man page.

[Managing Yosemite’s FileVault 2 with fdesetup](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/02/02/managing-yosemites-filevault-2-with-fdesetup/)

[Managing Mavericks’ FileVault 2 with fdesetup](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/managing-mavericks-filevault-2-with-fdesetup/)

Comment: IMHO this is more of a comment than an answer...